# How to associate opening in particular app with a keyboard/mouse shortcut?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, irfanview

I am looking for a method that would allow opening files in particular non-default apps by using shortcuts instead of tedious right-click > "Open In" > find an app (which might not even be there) routine.

Specifically, I am opening a lot of image files in IrfanView while it is not the default app (and I cannot change the default due to other usages), and the necessity of right-clicking makes the process very slow. I would enjoy the ability of, say, associating "Ctrl-Enter" or even (better) "Ctrl-right click" over a file with the action "Open in IrfanView". My attempts to look for a solution show many options of opening apps, but no information about opening files in apps when clicking on files. I am open to various kinds of solutions (native PowerShell scripts, some hidden Windows settings, opensource extension apps, settings of IrfanView itself).

Comment: You might try a tool such as AutoHotkey, which can act on a key/mouse button combo. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113468/ahk-capture-key-combination-left-mouse-button-with-other-key